# Is there a quick way to ignore certain values of an array when performing numpy operations?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, mask

Sorry if the title is confusing, but it is very hard to put what I would like to do in a single sentence. Image you have an image stack `stack` in the form of `N` `m x n` matrices as a numpy array in the shape of `(m, n, N)`. Now, if I want to perform the `numpy.median` for example along the stack axis `N` it is very easy: `numpy.median(stack, 0)`. The problem is that for each image of the stack, I also have a mask of pixels that I would not like to include in the operation, in this case `numpy.median`. Is there any efficient way to do that?

So far, all I could think of is this, but it is *increadibly* slow and absolutely not feasible:

```
median = [[]]*images[0].flatten().shape
for i in range(len(images)):
    image = images[i].flatten()
    mask = mask[i].flatten()
    for j in range(len(median)):
        if mask[j] == 0:
            median[j].append(image[j])
for i in range(len(median)):
    median[j] = np.median(median[j]) if median[j] else 0

median = np.array(median).reshape(images[0].shape)
```

There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is build a an array with `NaNs` in the non-masked values and compute `np.nanmedian` (which ignores `NaNs`). You can build such an array "on the fly" using `np.where`:

```
x = np.arange(4*3*4).reshape((4,3,4))
m = x%2 == 0
np.nanmedian(np.where(m, x, np.NaN), axis=2)
>>array([[ 1.,  5.,  9.],
       [13., 17., 21.],
       [25., 29., 33.],
       [37., 41., 45.]])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Although in my case the axis would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to say, but hopefully this will help:

You can use `np.where`to find and replace - or ignore/remove - values that you want to exclude.

Or you can use `bin_mask = stack != value_you_want_to_ignore` to get a boolean array that you can use to ignore your critical values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time! Sorry if it is hard to understand, maybe I made it too abstract. The problem is actually a very pratical one. Image you have an image sequence with some object, e.g. a ball moving in the foreground. For each image I have a mask of that ball. Now I want to estimate the background from each image and I do that by taking the median for each pixel over the image stack. But if the ball is covering that pixel in a certain image, I want to ignore the corresponding value when calculating the median. Does that make more sense?